# Change Error response in web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I'm using token based authentication in my Web Api Application. 
In Login Request, If User enter wrong credentials, then it return a response error in this format.

In `GrantResourceOwnerCredentials` method

```
if (user == null)
    {
      context.SetError("The email or password is incorrect.");
      return;
    }
```

Which return response as

```
 {
      "error": "InvalidLogin",
      "error_description": "The email or password is incorrect."
    }
```

And in my application all the error response returned in this format

```
{
  "message": "Some Internal server error occurred."
}
```

So how can I change the error response of web api 
to

```
    {
      "message": "The email or password is incorrect."
    }
```

Comment: What is "my Application"? Is it consuming your Web Api Application?

Comment: can you post web api application code

Comment: @KrishnaChaithanyaMuthyala:  I have created a webAPi application.

Comment: @PranavPatel: see the updated question

Comment: So, you want to standardize all the responses from all your APIs? Is that it? Do you see any problem in standardizing? Or, you want to know what are the best practices?

Comment: @KrishnaChaithanyaMuthyala: I want to standardize . As in my application all the response error in that format so I want to change it too.

Comment: @Programmer, if your entire application is giving response in a standard format, probably there's a class which just has a string property called message. You can just instantiate that object with the required message and do a json serialization of that object. Will this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDITED : TRY THIS

```
string jsonString = "{\"message\": \"The email or password is incorrect.\"}";
context.SetError(new string(' ',jsonString.Length-12)); 
context.Response.StatusCode = 400;
context.Response.Write(jsonString);
```

Comment: No it will response `{
      "error": "message",
      "error_description": "The email or password is incorrect."
    }`

Comment: why `jsonString.Length-12` ?

Comment: to remove the portion `\"message\":`

Comment: how can I return `"{\"message\": \"The email or password is incorrect.\",\"error_code\": \"400.\"}";`  And Also can you please did you remove `\"message\":`